# Como usar 2 endereços na condição do if ( !strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] , '/') )

Tags: php, javascript, html

O que fazer para usar dois endereços ao mesmo tempo nessa condição?

OBS.: Preciso que que esse código não carregue o HTML se um ou outro endereço for acessado

```
<?php 
if ( !strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] , '/') ){ 
?> 
<a id="seloEbit" href="http://www.ebit.com.br/90809" target="_blank" data-noop="redir(this.href);"> </a> 
<script type="text/javascript" id="getSelo" src="https://imgs.ebit.com.br/ebitBR/selo-ebit/js/getSelo.js?90809"> </script> 
<?php 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Não saquei bem, você quer adicionar esse JS e esse link se a página for acessada na home?

Comment: Não, eu só não coloquei o endereço ali e usei o "/" de exemplo. Eu preciso que esse html NÃO carregue se for acessada 'checkout/librepag' ou 'gerencianet/success&payment'

Comment: `if (condition1 || condition2) { /* Code Here */ }` ou `preg_grep()`, ou ainda `switch ($var) { /* Code Here */ }` ??

Comment: Tentei usar if ( !strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] , 'gerencianet/success&payment') || !strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] , 'checkout/librepag')) e não funcionou. É assim mesmo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o operador lógico `&&`:

```
<?php 
if ( !strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] , 'alguma coisa') && !strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] , 'outra coisa') ){ 
?> 
<a id="seloEbit" href="http://www.ebit.com.br/90809" target="_blank" data-noop="redir(this.href);"> </a> 
<script type="text/javascript" id="getSelo" src="https://imgs.ebit.com.br/ebitBR/selo-ebit/js/getSelo.js?90809"> </script> 
<?php 
} 
?>
```

Significa que ambas condições devem ser falsas para entrar no `if`.

Answer (score 0):

Há várias formas de fazer essa verificação:

**Exemplo 1:** Aqui nós utilizaremos o  `if` com o `OR` ou simplesmente `||`.

```
$request_uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

if(
    strpos($request_uri, "checkout/librepag") === false ||
    strpos($request_uri, "gerencianet/success&payment") === false
){
    echo "Exibe html";
}
```

> Funciona, porém se o valor de **REQUEST_URI** for *gerencianet/success&orderId=998787&payment*, ele não vai funcionar.

**Exemplo 2:** Aqui nós utilizaremos o `if` com `Regex (Expressão Regular)`

```
$request_uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

if(
    !preg_match("/(checkout\/librepag|gerencianet\/success.+&payment)/", $request_uri)
){
    echo "Exibe html";
}
```

> Funciona para qualquer valor que possua `checkout/librepag` e `gerencianet/success&payment`. Ou seja, vai funcionar para: **1.** *gerencianet/success&orderId=998787&payment*, **2.** *checkout/librepag* e também **3.** *ZZZZZ/checkout/librepag/ZZZZZ*

Comment: Usei o segundo exemplo, mas não funcionou como você descreveu

Comment: Qual o valor da variável `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` quando você tenta? Se possível adiciona `echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];` antes do `if` e posta aqui o resultado.

Comment: aparece isso:
/index.php?route=checkout/librepag
E carrega o html